# How to remove border points from InputForm?

Tags: plotting, image-processing, output-formatting

I have this code, and it generates the below `ListStreamPlot`.  The second graph is the `ListStreamPlot` overlaid with the points comprising the `ListStreamPlot` (extracted after looking at `// InputForm`); unfortunately, the extracted points also include the border points.  These "border points" are not of predictable coordinates, so there doesn't seem to be an easy way to remove them from the set.  (I want this code to be as case-inspecific as possible, since I am analyzing many additional data sets.)

Is there a simple way -- perhaps in the original `ListStreamPlot` code -- to remove the "border points" from the points list?

```
v3 = ListStreamPlot[vectorsT, StreamStyle -> "Line", StreamPoints -> 
  {{xcorT[[midpoint + 4]], ycorT[[midpoint + 4]]}}]

points = v3[[1, 2, 1]];

xPoints = Transpose[points][[1]]; 
yPoints = Transpose[points][[2]];

pointsOnly = ListPlot[Transpose[Join[{xPoints}, {yPoints}]]] ;
```

graph 1:

[image]

graph 2:

[image]

**Entire source code**

```
(* Set directory to that of this notebook *)
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];

(* Import CSV'd data *)
dat = Import["test_data2b.txt", "CSV"];

(* Divide data *)
datAll = Flatten[Partition[dat[[1]], 7]];
datAllCpy = datAll;

(* Divide data into components *)
(* ID *)

ID = Flatten[Partition[datAll, 1, 7]];
datAll = RotateLeft[datAll];

(* Longitude *)
LONG = Flatten[Partition[datAll, 1, 7]];
datAll = RotateLeft[datAll];

(* Latitude *)
LAT = Flatten[Partition[datAll, 1, 7]];
datAll = RotateLeft[datAll];

(* SFC_SPD *)
SPD1 = Flatten[Partition[datAll, 1, 7]];
datAll = RotateLeft[datAll];

(* SPF_SPD _KT *)
SPD2 = Flatten[Partition[datAll, 1, 7]];
datAll = RotateLeft[datAll];

(* SFC_SPD _MP *)
SPD3 = Flatten[Partition[datAll, 1, 7]];
datAll = RotateLeft[datAll];

(* SFC_DIR *)
DIR = Flatten[Partition[datAll, 1, 7]];

(* Restore original list *)
datAll = datAllCpy;

(* Make longtitudes negative *)
LONG = Abs[LONG];
LONG = 0 - LONG;

(* Convert from degrees to radians *)
DIR = DIR *(2 Pi/360);

(* Graph data as vectors *)
xcor = LONG;
ycor = LAT;
xvc = SPD1*Cos[DIR]; 
yvc = SPD1*Sin[DIR];
vectors = Table[{{xcor[[i]], ycor[[i]]}, {-yvc[[i]], -xvc[[i]]}}, {i, 1, Length[xcor]}];

(* Calculate midpoint of data *)
midpoint = Flatten[Position[SPD1, 0.]][[1]];

(* Transpose all points to be around origin *)
LONGT = LONG - (LONG[[midpoint]]);
LATT = LAT - LAT[[midpoint]]; 

(* Graph data as vectors *)
xcorT = LONGT;
ycorT = LATT;
xvcT = SPD1*Cos[DIR]; 
yvcT = SPD1*Sin[DIR];
vectorsT = Table[{{xcorT[[i]], ycorT[[i]]}, {-yvcT[[i]], -xvcT[[i]]}}, {i, 1, Length[xcor]}];

v3 = ListStreamPlot[vectorsT, StreamStyle -> "Line", StreamPoints -> {{xcorT[[midpoint + 4]], ycorT[[midpoint + 4]]}}]

points = v3[[1, 2, 1]]; 

xPoints = Transpose[points][[1]]; 
yPoints = Transpose[points][[2]];

pointsOnly = ListPlot[Transpose[Join[{xPoints}, {yPoints}]]] ;

Show[v3, pointsOnly]
```

Comment: Please include full executable code so that we can try this ourselves without first having to recreate your example.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes - I have added it above.

Comment: Okay, but now we lack the `test_data2b.txt` file.  Is it not possibly to give a smaller self-contained example of the problem?

Comment: Yes, just about to address that.  The data can be found here - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kojtOSegNd0jHYiGt_8if5FuCmlad5pm72IIon6pbKU/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the `Line` first, then extract the points on the line:

```
pts = Cases[v3,
   GraphicsComplex[c__] :>
    Cases[Normal[GraphicsComplex[c]],
     Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity],
   Infinity] // Flatten[#, 2]& ;
Graphics[{Red, Point[pts]}, Frame -> True ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @ueronica You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

You could abuse the `StreamColorFunction` for this goal

```
res=
Reap[
  v3 = ListStreamPlot[vectorsT, 
          StreamStyle -> "Line", 
          StreamPoints -> {{xcorT[[midpoint + 4]], ycorT[[midpoint + 4]]}}, 
          StreamColorFunction -> ((Sow[{#1, #2}]; None) &)
       ]
];

ListPlot[res[[2]], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]